# Combinatorial problems that were solved using the representation theory of finite groups?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, big-list

> **Question:** What are some examples of problems in combinatorics that were solved using the representation theory of finite groups ?

I am aware the representation theory of finite groups plays a role in solving problems in number theory, for example [automorphic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_form). But what are some (important) examples from combinatorics.

---

1. We have the following paper from Diaconis: [Group Representations in Probability and Statistics](https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9140a-2012-summer/Diaconis.pdf). In particular are the results related to card shuffling.

Comment: IIRC, various instances of cyclic sieving have been proven using representation theory first, and only later (if at all) combinatorially. One survey is https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0790 (but there is newer work around, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bruce Sagan's book, $The$ $Symmetric$ $Group$ (second edition), he proves a unimodality theorem using representation theory---if I recall correctly, for the poset called $L(m,n)$---but this wasn't the first proof of that theorem (Corollary 5.4.10).